# Smart way of simplifying an expression with square roots?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have some long expressions with square roots in them, but I know that if I can simplify these expressions, the result shouldn't have square roots. But Mathematica is not able to simplify these expression. Assume all the variables are large than 0.

```
((5 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)] (2 hh^2 + 3 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)] + 
  2 hh (3 + Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]))^2 (9 + 8 hh^2 + 
  12 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)] + 8 hh (3 + Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]))^3 (hh^2 + 
  4 hH (-1 + 4 hH) + hh (-1 + 8 hH)) (-1 + hh + 4 hL) (hh + 
  4 hL))/((-1 + c + 8 hh) (hh + Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]) (3 + hh + Sqrt[
  hh (3 + hh)]) (-3 + 2 hh + 2 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]) (3 + 2 hh + 
  2 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)])^5 (9 + 2 hh + 2 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]) (3 + 
  4 hh + 4 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)]) (9 + 4 hh + 4 Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)])))// Simplify[#, hh > 0 && hL > 0 && hH > 0 && c > 0] &
```

I've tried Expand, FullSimplify, etc, but non of them works.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: You can get rid of all the Sqrt's by exp /. {Sqrt[hh (3 + hh)] -> x} where exp is your expression.

Comment: @bills Hey, this is just one of examples, in my other expressions, the square roots may be other form and may have different expressions in the square roots. And I'm looking for an universal way of dealing with these square roots. But thanks, anyway!

Comment: `Simplify` after `ComplexExpand` rearranges things, but makes more `Sqrt` expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work if you first `Expand` your expression fully, then use the assumption that you know you can make to help `Simplify` (`expr` is your expression from the OP):

```
Simplify[ExpandAll@expr, Assumptions -> (_ > 0)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The option `Assumptions -> (_ > 0)` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, in this case. However, the OP had mentioned that they have other similar expressions where perhaps the assumption might help. I wanted to show how to quickly include a "global" assumption, as an expedient alternative to listing each symbol individually.

Comment: Does `Assumptions -> (_ > 0)` do what you think it does?  I don't think `Assumptions` works with patterns, unless that is a V11.3 innovation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think it does. Try `Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], Assumptions -> _ \[Element] Reals]` with and without the `Assumptions` bit.

Comment: Apparently it sometimes works. Compare `Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], Assumptions -> x < 0]` with `Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], Assumptions -> _ < 0]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hmm interesting. I have been using this form, admittedly invariably to indicate that some symbols have positive values, and I didn't realize it would work only *sometimes*. Thank you for pointing this out, I need to go take another look at some code of mine!

Comment: I have no insight to when it does and when it does not work, btw.  (It failed for me in the past, and I just wrote it off, a little too hastily perhaps.)