# Properly simplifying a complicated expression with square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm having trouble simplifying (a family of) complicated rational expressions.  For instance, I obtained the following
$$
expr=\frac{\sqrt{3} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\tau ^3 (\tau +2) (\lambda -\tau +1) (\lambda +\tau +2)}{\lambda  (\lambda +3)}}}{(\tau +1) (2 \tau +1)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{\tau  (\tau +2)}
   (\lambda -2 \tau  (\tau +2))}{\sqrt{\lambda  (\lambda +3)} (4 \tau  (\tau +2)+3)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) (\tau +1)^2 (2 \tau +3)^2}{\tau  (\tau +2)^3
   (\lambda -\tau ) (\lambda +\tau +3)}}}\right)}{\sqrt{(\lambda +1) (\lambda +2)}}
$$
as a result of

```
FullSimplify[expr,  Assumptions -> {lambda> 0, tau > 0, tau <= lambda}]
```

Here's the same expression in `InputForm`:

```
 expr = (Sqrt[3]*(Sqrt[((1 + lambda - tau)*tau^3*(2 + tau)*(2 + lambda + tau))/(lambda*(3 + lambda))]/((1 + tau)*(1 + 2*tau)) - 
   1/Sqrt[(lambda*(3 + lambda)*(1 + tau)^2*(3 + 2*tau)^2)/((lambda - tau)*tau*(2 + tau)^3*(3 + lambda + tau))] + 
   (2*Sqrt[tau*(2 + tau)]*(lambda - 2*tau*(2 + tau)))/(Sqrt[lambda*(3 + lambda)]*(3 + 4*tau*(2 + tau)))))/Sqrt[(1 + lambda)*(2 + lambda)]
```

There are clear additional simplifications, such as factors of $\sqrt{(\tau+1)^2}$, commons factors of $\lambda (\lambda+3)$ and the last term, with the inverse fraction in the denominator, is annoying because when $\lambda=\tau$ it appears there is a $0$ in one of the denominators.

I followed the suggestion of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171691/smart-way-of-simplifying-an-expression-with-square-roots)

```
FullSimplify[ExpandAll@expr,  Assumptions -> {lambda> 0, tau > 0, tau<= lambda}]
```

but this returns
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3} \tau  \sqrt{\frac{(\tau +2) (\tau +3)}{(\lambda +1) (\lambda +2)}} \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda ^3 (\lambda +3)}{\tau  (\tau +3)}}+2
   \sqrt{\frac{\lambda ^3 (\lambda +3) \tau }{\tau +3}}-4 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau ^5}{\tau +3}}-12 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau
   ^3}{\tau +3}}+2 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau ^3 (\lambda -\tau +1) (\lambda +\tau +2)}{\tau +3}}-2 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau ^3
   (\lambda -\tau ) (\lambda +\tau +3)}{\tau +3}}-8 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau }{\tau +3}}+3 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) \tau  (\lambda
   -\tau +1) (\lambda +\tau +2)}{\tau +3}}-2 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda  (\lambda +3) (\lambda -\tau ) (\lambda +\tau +3)}{\tau  (\tau +3)}}-5 \sqrt{\frac{\lambda 
   (\lambda +3) \tau  (\lambda -\tau ) (\lambda +\tau +3)}{\tau +3}}\right)}{\lambda  (\lambda +3) (\tau +1) (2 \tau +1) (2 \tau +3)}
$$
which removes some of the irksome problems of apparently singular expressions in denominators (although the $\tau$ factor in front would cancel some denominator factors of $\sqrt{\tau}$ thus removing the singularity issue for $\tau=0$) but is not that much better as there are still lots of common factors, again like $\sqrt{\lambda(\lambda+3)}$ and $\sqrt{\tau+3}$.

This one expression turns out to be always $<0$ over the allowed range of $\tau$ so I thought of multiplying by $-1$, squaring and taking the square root but this doesn't seem productive (and is very time consuming) because the square roots don't go away "nicely" upon squaring.

This is one of a series of expression of similar structure (always a sum of $3$ terms) and complexity so I wonder if there is a better way to proceed, possibly starting from the last expression, to properly factor the common terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand), although it will need some help to arrive at your desired goal. Note that by default [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) makes assumptions about symbols that may not be true, meaning that the power expanded form may not be equal to the original form. However, you can use the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option of [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand), in which case you should expect that the power expanded form is a simplification of the original form. In this case, the default assumptions are probably ok:

```
PowerExpand[expr] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{3} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\tau +2} \tau ^{3/2} \sqrt{\lambda -\tau +1} \sqrt{\lambda +\tau
>    +2}}{\sqrt{\lambda } \sqrt{\lambda +3} (\tau +1) (2 \tau +1)}-\frac{(\tau +2)^{3/2} \sqrt{\tau }
>    \sqrt{\lambda -\tau } \sqrt{\lambda +\tau +3}}{\sqrt{\lambda } \sqrt{\lambda +3} (\tau +1) (2 \tau
>    +3)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{\tau +2} \sqrt{\tau } (\lambda -2 \tau  (\tau +2))}{\sqrt{\lambda } \sqrt{\lambda
>    +3} (4 \tau  (\tau +2)+3)}\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda +1} \sqrt{\lambda +2}}$

Here's the version where you give explicit assumptions:

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions->0<tau<=lambda] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{3} \tau ^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{(\tau +2) (\lambda -\tau +1) (\lambda +\tau +2)}{\lambda  (\lambda
>    +1) (\lambda +2) (\lambda +3)}}}{(\tau +1) (2 \tau +1)}-\frac{\sqrt{3} (\tau +2)^{3/2} \sqrt{\lambda
>    -\tau } \sqrt{\frac{\tau  (\lambda +\tau +3)}{\lambda  (\lambda +1) (\lambda +2) (\lambda +3)}}}{(\tau
>    +1) (2 \tau +3)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{\tau  (\tau +2)}{\lambda  (\lambda +1) (\lambda +2)
>    (\lambda +3)}} (\lambda -2 \tau  (\tau +2))}{4 \tau  (\tau +2)+3}$

Comment: As an update: a little more mileage was obtained by "manually" identifying the common terms and finally using PowerExpand[Sqrt[$\lambda (1+\lambda)(2+\lambda)(3+\lambda)$ expr /$\sqrt{3\tau(2+\tau)}$,Assumptions...] and this is good enough for the expressions I have to deal with.  This gets rids of the troublesome singularities in the denominator.